# How to get the returned rows after executing a PHP/MYSQL prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I know the output of an execute statement is a bool. But then how do you get the result of a SELECT statement like below?

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

$sth will be either TRUE or FALSE. What I'm interested in is the return rows containing the name, colour and etc.

Thanks!

Comment: See [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: I know its a **RADICAL IDEA** but you could always try [Reading the manual its even written in many languages](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You know , I'm sorry if I'm wrong but doesn't this look like a textbook problem?  As in, it comes from a textbook?

Comment: I've already tried: while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {$returnValue["items"][]=$row;} but I was getting an error saying Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object. I thought I'm not supposed to do fetch() on a function that returns a bool.

Comment: Then your query FAILED

Comment: I got this example from PHP manual. But I couldn't find out what to do after the execute: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Add this code to test for error and display an error message http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Don't jump on conclusion guys...I was missing $sth->get_result() after the execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $sth->get_result();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

    echo $row['name'];

}
```

Comment: `fetch ( array( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) ` array??

Comment: This gives me an error: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @AliM Check the following edit

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was missing $result = $sth->get_result();